# Find the CFG for $a^n b^m c^k$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a language like this and will need to write the Context-free grammar for it.

$$\{a^n b^m c^k\; : \;k = |n-m|,\; m, n, k \geq 0\}$$

What I am confused is do I need to simplify the condition of k = |n-m| to solve or it just means the length

Comment: $c^{n} \over c^{m}$, eliminating k the parameter?

Comment: @Jossie, huh? You cannot divide here...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez k = m - n.

Comment: @Jossie Perhaps you don't understand the expression - $a$, $b$ and $c$ are _symbols_, not _numbers_.  You cannot 'divide by' powers of $c$.

Comment: Sorry. Please excuse my comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider breaking it into the two cases $n\geq m$, $k=n-m$ and $m\gt n$, $k=m-n$; if you can find grammars for these two cases then you can just union them together to get your final CFG.  As a further hint, note that in each case you can eliminate the larger of $m$ and $n$ in favor of $k$ and the smaller one; for instance, in the case $n\geq m$ then $n=m+k$ and so that 'half' of the grammar can be written as $a^{m+k}b^mc^k$ - or, more suggestively, $a^ka^mb^mc^k$.  Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: Thanks, I came up with this: S -> X; X -> aXc|aUb|epsilon; U -> aUb|epsilon

Comment: @Herious That should work, although you probably want just 'U' rather than 'aUb' in the first expression; remember that you might have $m=0$.  You should be able to handle the other case ($m\geq n$) in much the same way; can you see how?

Comment: I came up with this a^n b^n b^k c^k for the grammar with m = n+k

Comment: Yep - and that should be an easy CFG to write (it starts, for instance, 'Y->VW' where V handles the $a^nb^n$ portion and W handles the $b^kc^k$ portion).  Well-done!

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, I got this: Y -> VZ|epsilon ; V -> aVb|epsilon ; Z -> bZc|epsilon

Comment: yeah and I think from the beginning, the absolute value would be divided into 2 cases with OR connection, so I would write S -> X|Y|epsilon , is that correct?

Comment: @Herious Exactly, although the 'epsilon' is actually redundant there (and in fact, it's redundant in Y's definition as well) since both productions for S (and both parts of Y) can produce empty strings themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing, $k=n-m$ is the required condition, so we can show that $n=m+k$,
i.e for every $b$ there must be an $a$ and for every $c$ there must be an $a$. So the language can be written as:

S -> aSc | aTb
T -> aTb | ab

Comment: Welcome to math.SX! In order to make your answer easier to read and understand, please [format](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) your post.